How to patch the drywall around this jbox
I need to patch the drywall around this jbox for my electrician to put in a new outlet. But I’m unsure how far to go in with the drywall and the best way to attach such small pieces.


Hard to know what we are looking at here.  Is that a baseboard next to an oddly shaped hole hacked out of a wall?  Any particular reason why it's shaped like that?

In general, a large drywall repair/patch is easier than a small one.

Cut back to the stud on the left. Give yourself 3/4” bearing minimum.
Pull off the baseboard. Cut to the right, either to the middle of the next stud or 3” over from the jbox. If you didn’t go to the stud, put a chunk of plywood on the seam to act as backer.
Put a new piece of drywall between the supports. Tape, skim, sand, repeat as necessary and paint. Fix the baseboard (maybe with a whole new piece, or maybe with the piece that got removed initially).

+1. Additionally, it looks like a deeper mud ring (the "cover plate" screwed to the face of the box, into which the receptacle itself will be screwed) would be appropriate. It appears that the mounting holes of this one are nowhere near the surface of the drywall, meaning that the receptacle won't be able to be screwed down very well, leaving a wobbly and unsatisfactory installation.

Good point, @FreeMan. If that’s a 1/2” mud ring, 5/8” are readily available, and probably others at specialty places. That said, if I’m remembering code, you can use up to 1/4” of spacers to flush and solidify the receptacle.

You can use spacers, but it's a pain!
